# Android Connection pooling

Tags: android, http, connection, pooling

For implementing http connection pooling, I had gone through [this link](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html). After reading this I came to conclusion that making a single Http client object and connection manager with different request and responses will take care of  connection pooling.

My question is, am I thinking correct or not?? Please tell me how connections will be faster by implementing this.Please let me know if you have any sample ANDROID project where http connection pooling is implemented. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why implement a connection pool and use one?

Comment: Making connection objects like http client  is costly operation.It consumes a lot of time.So if u implement a pooling for multiple request case then communication will be faster.